# Why am I unable to activate this specific feature in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have inherited a `Sharepoint 2013` environment which I now need to manage. I have created a new `list` for a new `Discussion Board`.

My issue is that it does not allow me to insert `videos` into my posts. Regarding `images`, all work fine. Some research have pointed towards the need to activate located under `Site Settings` > `Site Collection Features` > `Video and Rich Media`.

However when I press the `Activate` button, I get the following `error message`:

```
Dependency feature 'DocumentManagement' (id: 3a4ce811-6fe0-4e97-a6ae-675470282cf2) for 
feature 'DocumentSet' (id: 3bae86a2-776d-499d-9db8-fa4cdc7884f8) is not activated 
at this scope.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I had to activate `Document Sets metadata synchronization` (located in `Web Application Feature`) prior to activating the `Video and Rich Media`feature.